# Splunk How can I do this in python SSL

Tags: python, ssl, connection, certificate, splunk

I need to your help. When I am using python to `Splunk Connection`, I saw this error. I'm using python 2.7

`SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)`

So, I saw that reference pages like this 
https://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/PythonSDK/1.6.5/client.html#splunklib.client.Indexes

But I still can't resolve the above error.

When verifying connection, it returns `False`.

Do I need to add more into the settings?

Thank you.

```
 service = client.connect(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        username=username,
        password=password,
        verify=False
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed certificates or a certificate signed by an untrusted CA are both common reasons for verification failures, but not the only reasons. Expired certificates or using an IP address in your application when the certificate does not contain a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) IP entry to secure traffic to the IP address are also common issues.

One way to handle any failure is in the code using `verify=False` as in your example, although this is not really recommended as you're essentially disabling certificate verification which can be risky from a security standpoint. This is not suggested in production environments. However, it might be necessary in certain situations such as an expired certificate which you have no control over to replace it.

If it's a self-signed certificate or untrusted CA another way to handle this may be importing the self-signed certificate or the untrusted CA into your trusted certificate store, or Splunk's certificate store if it uses its own. Adding a certificate to your systems certificate store is different for each OS or even between distro's of Linux.

You can use your browser to examine SSL certificate and see if you get the same verification failure or not. Otherwise [this page](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/openssl-command-cheatsheet-b441be1e8c4a/), from freecodecamp, goes into some detail about using the openssl utility to examine certificates, identify the signer (CA or self signed) or download the certificate so you could import it into a store.

Separately [this discussion](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Building-for-the-Splunk-Platform/Splunk-Python-Env-CA-certificates/m-p/393340) at splunk.com has a very similar question and a solution that suggests using `openssl_capath_env` / `SSL_CERT_DIR` to resolve the verification failure when the certificate is not trusted.